# Cant static cast class to integer

Tags: c++, static-cast

Why am i getting a error when i try to static cast a element* to an int

```
typedef Element* ElementPtr

int Element::getVP (ElementPtr item)
{
return static_cast <int>(item); // I have a class called Element
}
```

Comment: Well why do you think?

Comment: What do you expect this to do? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: why, should i use a void pointer??? i dont understand

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Computernerd - void pointers are usually a bad idea.

Comment: Pointers don't convert to integers. Pointers are not integers. Pointers are pointers. Why do you need to do this? You probably don't. This means that you don't need a `void*`, either.

Comment: I am feeling what you want is `operator int()` for Element

Comment: For a pointer, `void *` is preferred above `int`, but ... what Ed said.

Comment: i am trying to have a function which use a element pointer to point to the int value of a element class

Comment: @Computernerd: What is "the int value of a element class"? Tell us what you are trying to do, and not how you've decided to do it.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have to make two steps back first and then tell us what it is you want to achieve. As for how you're trying to achieve it, all I know is that this is wrong.

Comment: How is `Element` defined and what would its `int` representation be (once you dereference the pointer)?

Comment: [A useful link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28037/1711796).

Comment: thanks everyone for their help, i got it figured out already thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what's your question, but I feel you want implicit conversion function.
To convert `Element` to int, you want `operator int()`

```
struct Element
{
  operator int()
  {
    return i;
  }
  int i;
};

int Element::getVP (Element* item)
{
  return (*item); // I have a class called Element
}
```

But it's still not clear why you need `getVP` in Element class.

It' just to show you how to convert struct/class to int type. I'll delete my answer if it's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to get a `int` from the Element and you have already overloaded the cast operator of the `Element` class like so:

```
operator int() { return m_some_int; }
```

you can use (assuming item is a pointer)

```
return (int)(*item);
```

Instead, if you're trying to get the address of the pointer you can do the following:

```
std::size_t Element::get_address(Element* item)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(item);
}
```